# Android Models - ARMv6 and ARMv7 Devices for Game Development?

Tags: android, architecture, mobile

I am learning Android Games Development, and I am using Corona SDK for 2D Games Development. The Corona SDK 2011.450 supports ARMv6 Android Devices, while the new version 2011.484 supports ARMv7 Android Devices. Can some one tell me Android Phones (Models) that are based on ARMv6 and those that are of ARMv7.

Example: Some searching showed me that my **LG Optimus One is ARM v6**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every device which is based on Cortex-A8 is ARM v7 which includes **Qualcomm Snapdragon**, **Samsung Hummingbird** and **Texas OMAP3**. And every device based on Cortex-A9 is also ARM v7. These includes **nVidia Tegra 2**, **Texas OMAP4**, **Samsung Exynos 4210**.

As you can see in the list below, a lot of devices uses these processors.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Android_devices

Comment: The real issue in many cases is to identify ARM v6 devices, which lack the NEON vector instruction set.

Comment: And to further complicate matters, the nVidia Tegra2 is ARMv7, but does not have NEON.

Answer (score 1):

Nexus one is ARM 7 :
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snapdragon_%28system_on_chip%29
It feature a 1 Ghz Qualcomm QSD8250 CPU.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a google play console login, Go to  "Release management" -> "Device Catlog", You will get the full list of android phones with instruction set, modal, android version etc. You can also export the full list as excel.

[image]